# How can I track a bitcoin transaction using Blockchain's API

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin

I'm working on a Node.js Application (v12) and it requires that I track any bitcoin transactions to a certain address.
I've looked into some node packages, but they're either outdated or they do not have what I need in order to track transactions. I'd prefer resources as an answer since I'd like to learn myself but code examples would absolutely work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a well documented, well maintained and recently updated (just 4 days ago) enterprise-level library for this from [BCoin](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin).

To know more, you can visit the github repo link above. Or their [main website](https://bcoin.io/).

And to quickly answer your question, part of their library running on your nodejs server, you can just do this to get all transactions from an address:

```
GET /tx/address/:address
```

This returns transaction objects array by address with support for segwit. The supported address types include p2pkh, p2sh, p2wpkh, and p2wsh. Addresses with hundreds, thousands or millions of transactions, will need to make multiple queries to request all transactions using the after query parameter. If no results are found an empty array will be returned. Results include both confirmed and unconfirmed transactions.

You can read the API directly [here](https://bcoin.io/api-docs/#get-tx-by-address).

Note that this is a quick answer to your question. You of course need to set up the whole library on your nodejs server first to get it properly running.

You need to enable index-address and index-tx in order to lookup transactions by address. Launch the bcoin daemon with these arguments or modify `bcoin.conf` to include the options:

```
bcoin --daemon --index-address=true --index-tx=true
```